# IBM Websphere MQ Depth count for multiple queues via mail by using c#.net

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

I have 7 windows services for handling IBM Websphere message queues and by using each of them I get message and count. So now I need a windows service which handles all the queues of their services and retrieves the message count.
Now i am connecting to those message queues separately by reading MQ details using INI File. 
I need a way to connect all the queues and retrieve queue depth so that i can get depth of the queues via mail.

Please help me on this..

Comment: For what purpose are you getting the queue depth? Are you writing some monitoring tool? Do you want some event to be triggered when queue depths reach certain level?

Comment: i am writing a monitoring tool..Yes, I need an event to be triggered when the depth exceeds some level..@Shashi

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the sample programs provided with the MQ installation, specifically the sample for inquire:

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q024210_.htm

By inquiring a queue you can get its depth:

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q087810_.htm

However it's generally not a hint of a good solution design when you are trying to get depth of queues.

Answer (score 0):

IBM MQ has built-in function to let applications know when a number of type of event occurs. For example when the number of messages in a queue (i.e. queue depth) reaches a certain limit or goes below a certain level, an event message is put a SYSTEM queue.. You just need to enable that functionality.

Queue depth related event messages are put to SYSTEM.ADMIN.PERFM.EVENT queue. So your application needs to listen to this queue and get messages as and when they arrive. The message will be in PCF format, hence you need to parse them accordingly.

See here for more details: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.mon.doc/q036420_.htm

This one is also useful:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/aimsupport/entry/websphere_mq_performance_events?lang=en